# Z-index for relative and absolute position?

Tags: css

It seems like z-index doesn't work with a div that has absolute position and that is relative to another div? I want the div that has absolute position to be below the other one, but I only get the opposite. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/t4g7r/) will show you the codes to make one div appear on top of another with positioning.

HTML

```
<div class="one">On top!</div>
<div class="two">Underneath</div>
```

CSS

```
.one
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.two
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    z-imdex: 2;
}
```

---

Update: Use only positioning to get the effect you want.

[Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4g7r/5/).

Comment: OK, but must not the div "two" be inside div "one", so that the closing tag for "one" is after tag "two"? And the on top div, should that not have the greates z-index?

Comment: A child element will inherit the parent's z-index. If you want it to appear as if it's on top, use positioning. I'll update.